# Django potential critical section

Tags: python, django, orm, transactions, critical-section

I have this situation in a Django REST Framework Application:

I have a delete View:

```
def delete(self, request, pk, lid=None, *args, **kwargs):

    user_info = self.get_object(pk)
    if user_info:
        location = Location.objects.filter(loc_id=lid).first()
        location.users.remove(user_info)
        if location.users.count() is 0:
            //delete location

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

I think that in this code there is a potential critical section:

- **flow - 1**: Check count location user -> count is 0
- **flow - 2**: Add new user (user2) into location user (by other view)
- **flow - 1**: Remove the location because location user is 0 (but this is not correct because flow-2 has added a new user_info).

Is it possible in Django to have this section (check value and delete operation)

```
location = Location.objects.filter(loc_id=lid).first()
location.users.remove(user_info)
if location.users.count() is 0:
   //delete location
```

atomically?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a transaction and make the DB the *situs* of [atomicity](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic):

> Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. **`atomic`** allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the database is guaranteed. If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back.

```
from django.db import transaction

def delete(self, request, pk, lid=None, *args, **kwargs):
    with transaction.atomic():
        user_info = self.get_object(pk)
        if user_info:
            location = Location.objects.filter(loc_id=lid).first()
            location.users.remove(user_info)
            if location.users.count() is 0:
                # delete location
                location.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```